# Ineractive logon message doesn't show?

Tags: windows-server-2003

We set the Group Policy for our Domain and OUs to show the logon message:

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\
Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on

but nothing happen when the client computer logon. I checked the RSOP.MSC to see the group policy that set and the message is set on client computer but it doesn't show at the logon prompt. so what should I do? We have Windows server 2003 AD and Windows XP Pro on client computer.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work??

Answer (score 1):

Check the results for `gpresult` from the command line. You should be able to tell if that group policy is being applied to the computer.
If it already is, you can try `gpupdate /force` to force the policy to update.

Comment: Yes, verify the login window policy is actually being applied to the client. Gpresult or RSOP.MSC can help with this. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323276

Comment: Thanks, I checked that and I can see the the policy and the message I have written on client, but it doesn't show the message window to user?!!!

Comment: What's the result of gpresult? There should be a section in there saying filtered out. Does that policy show up in there? 
You might also create a new group policy and get that to apply to the new OU to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also setting the message title?

The following (taken from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310430)) might also be impacting your results

"Note If you do not use carriage returns in your display message, the maximum number of characters that you can add to the logon box is 512. If you add carriage returns, you can add up to 2048 characters (512 characters per line)."

Comment: I checked all that article, still doesn't show anything. I also use title but nothing happen!

Comment: @user19049 - did you ever get this to work?  I am working on the same issue right now and I am unable to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning it to an OU with Users or Computers in it?

Comment: to OUs that have got users and Computers name